# Peace Lily in bad shape

Tags: houseplants, peace-lily

My peace lily plant fell off my shelf and landed on the ground, then stuff fell on the plant. The soil stayed together but the leaves are bent or broken completely what’s the chance of me bringing it back to life?

Answer (score 1):

Peace Lily is a perennial so there is a good chance. Ruthlessly cut away the broken leaves to leave just the root and any remaining intact leaf pieces. Replant the root at its original depth, place in medium but not high light, keep moist and wait to see what happens. The root should still have enough resources to keep the plant going while it establishes new leaves.